# class in proc tabulate not working

Tags: sas

Hi my dataset looks something like this:

```
Var1    Var2    mainvar
  1      0       1
  0      0       1
  1      1       3
  0      0       2
  1      1       5
  1      1       4
  0      0       3
```

I want to tabulate Var1 and Var2 based on the value of mainvar (which ranges from 1 to 5) so I tried:

```
%let class=Var1 Var2  
proc tabulate data=x noseps missing FORMCHAR='    ';  
class &class mainvar;  
table &class;  
run;
```

But this is giving me the table without the data being factored by values of mainvar. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: You need a tables statement

Comment: Fixed! Do I need a variable statement?

Comment: It all depends what table you are trying to produce.  Tables &class,mainvar will give you a frequency table with Var1 and Var2 as rows and mainvar as column.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I think it's best to create a reproducible example.  The following works fine for me:

```
data example ; 
input var1 var2 mainvar ; 
cards;
  1      0       1
  0      0       1
  1      1       3
  0      0       2
  1      1       5
  1      1       4
  0      0       3
;
run;


%let class=Var1 Var2 ; 
proc tabulate data=example noseps missing FORMCHAR='    ';  
class &class mainvar;  
table &class;  
run;
```